# How do you force the wordpress dashboard to be 1 coulmn by default?

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

How do you force the wordpress dashboard to be 1 coulmn by default? I want to show the dashboard as a single column for all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a promising looking answer to this question in the following post:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/customizing-admin-area-using-functionsphp-2-questions

It recommends using this code in the functions.php file:

```
function so_screen_layout_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['dashboard'] = 1;
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'screen_layout_columns', 'so_screen_layout_columns' );

function so_screen_layout_dashboard() {
    return 1;
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'so_screen_layout_dashboard' );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way to force 3 column dashboard for a certain browser width?

Comment: Wow, great question @Amjad! I've moved away from WP over the years, but I would think that you'd need to capture the width using .js upon window resize and re-query the WP back end when the browser reached the desired width. Sorry I don't have a better answer, perhaps someone else will comment more specifically.